# React+Node webpage - Update endpoint throws 404 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have setup a webpage to search a number via user input and if it's available in the `SQL Server` database, 2 text boxes would show up with the data using `AXIOS GET` endpoint. Then I'm trying to get those ID's of the data rows and if the user needs to `UPDATE` it, then `UPDATE` it via `AXIOS PUT` endpoint. The issue is once user clicks the `UPDATE` button it throws an error `PUT http://localhost:5000/api/customerOrder/[object%20Object],[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)`

***Here's what I've tried***

**Server endpoints :**

`dboperations.js`

```
var config = require('./dbconfig');
const sql = require('mssql');

async function getallcustomerOrders(){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .query("SELECT * FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] order by ID desc");
        return orders.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function getcustomerOrders(orderNumber){
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .input('input_parameter', sql.NChar, orderNumber)
            .query("SELECT ID,cmt FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] where LTRIM(ord_no) = LTRIM(@input_parameter)");
        return orders.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async function updateComments(ID){
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let orders = await pool.request()
            .input('ID', sql.NChar, ID)
            .query(`SELECT ID,cmt FROM [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] WHERE ID = @ID`);

        let order = orders.recordset.length ? orders.recordset[0] : null;
        if (order) {
            await pool.request()
                .input('cmt', req.body.cmt)
                .query(`UPDATE [100].[dbo].[OELINCMT_SQL] SET cmt = @cmt WHERE ID = @ID;`);

            order = { ...order, ...req.body };

            res.json(order);
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Record not found'
            });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
}



module.exports = {
    getallcustomerOrders : getallcustomerOrders,
    getcustomerOrders : getcustomerOrders,
    updateComments : updateComments
}
```

`api.js`

```
var Db = require('./dboperations');
var dboperations = require('./dboperations');

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
const { request, response } = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/api', router);

router.use((request,response,next)=> {
    console.log('middleware');
    next();
})

router.route('/customerOrder').get((request,response)=>{
    dboperations.getallcustomerOrders().then(result => {
        response.json(result[0]);
        console.log(result[0]);
    })
})

router.route('/customerOrder/:orderNumber').get((request,response)=>{
    dboperations.getcustomerOrders(request.params.orderNumber).then(result => {
        response.json(result[0]);
        console.log(result[0]);
    })
})

router.route('customerOrder/:ID').put((request,response)=>{
    dboperations.updateComments(request.params.ID).then(result => {
        response.json(result[0]);
        console.log(result[0]);
    })
})

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Customer Order API is running at ' + port);

dboperations.getcustomerOrders().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})

dboperations.getallcustomerOrders().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})

dboperations.updateComments().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Client :

`EmailFaxDetails.js` : This is the page user enters the number

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import FetchOrderDetails from './FetchOrderDetails';
import axios from 'axios'
import '../App.css';

const EmailFaxDetails = () => {

    const [orderNumber, setOrderNumber] = useState('');
    const [id, setId] = useState([]);
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

    const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/customerOrder/${orderNumber}`
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          setId(response.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }, [url]);


  const handleChange = event => {
    setOrderNumber(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsShown(true);
    console.log(orderNumber);
    
  }

    return(
        <div>
            
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            Order Number: <input placeholder="Order Number" type="text" id="message" name="message" onChange={handleChange} value={orderNumber} autoComplete="off" />
                {id.map((idnum) => (
                    <div key={idnum.ID}>
                      <br></br>
                      ID : {idnum.ID}
                    </div>
                ))}
            
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Search</button>
            {isShown && <FetchOrderDetails ord_no={orderNumber} ID={id}/>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default EmailFaxDetails;
```

`FetchOrderDetails.js` : In this page user get's the output if the number is available in SQL server and let then UPDATE accordingly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../App.css';

const FetchOrderDetails = ({ord_no,ID}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/customerOrder/${ord_no}`
      useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          setData(response.data)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }, [url]);

    const url2 = `http://localhost:5000/api/customerOrder/${ID}`
    const onSubmit = () => {
        axios.put(url2)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            alert("Comment successfully updated");
            ID.history.push(`/customerOrder/${ord_no}`);
          } else Promise.reject();
        })
        .catch((err) => alert("Something went wrong"));
      }
    

    if(data) {
        return(
            <div>
                {data.map((order) => (
                    <div key={order.ID}>
                      <br></br>
                      ID : {order.ID}
                      <br></br>
                      Email/Fax: <input defaultValue={order.cmt} placeholder="Sales Ack Email" id="salesAck" style={{width: "370px"}} />
                    </div>
                ))}
                <div>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                  <button onClick={onSubmit}>Update</button>
                </div> 
          </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <h1>Something went wrong, please contact IT!</h1>
    )
}

export default FetchOrderDetails;
```

What I suspect is the issue might be coming from the `EmailFaxDetails.js` page while trying to pass the `ID` since there are 2 ID's per number the user search. I might be wrong, if anyone could find the error and help making it correct I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here
setId(response.data)

You need retrieve only id and same for for orderid